# Expectation of the square root of exponential-like function when the random variable is Gaussian

Tags: integration, random-variables, expected-value

Given a function $g(x_1,x_2)=1-f(x_1)e^{-\frac{(x_2-b)^2}{2}}$ and suppose the condition distribution of $x_2$ given $x_1$ is a normal distribution, $p(x_2\mid x_1)\sim\mathcal{N}(cx_1+d,\sigma^2)$, here $b,c,d,\sigma$ are all constants and $f$ is a function w.r.t $x_1$. I would like to know if we can obstain the explicit form of the function $h(x_1)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x_2\mid x_1)}[\sqrt{g(x_1,x_2)}]$. Can we achieve that? I think it is quite easy to calculate $\mathbb{E}_{p(x_2\mid x_1)}[g(x_1,x_2)]$ but I don't know how to deal with the square root. If not, it there any good way to approximate $h(x_1)$?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "$b,c,d,\sigma$ are all constants", but so is $x_1. \qquad$

Comment: $$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1-f(x_1)\exp\left(-\frac{(u-b)^2}{2}\right)} \cdot \exp\left( -\frac 1 2 \left( \frac{u-(cx_1+d)} \sigma \right)^2 \right) \left( \frac{du} \sigma \right)
$$

Comment: Since you haven't said what function $f$ is, we may as well just regard $cx_1+d$ and $f(x_1)$ as two separate constants. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes we can think of them as constants, actually my question is, can we get the form with no integration? Thanks!